# iTunes + Music app: how to sync star ratings?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, music

I have ~60gb of music on iTunes 12 and a 16gb iPhone 6.

1. I want to have music on my phone while saving some space for photos and apps
2. I want to be able to add star ratings to my music while listening on my phone and have that sync to my iTunes.  This way I can remove unwanted music from my collection while curating my "best music" smart playlist.

I used to be able do to 1 + 2, but since the most recent update to the Music app, I can only do 1.  Is there any way to do both?